# Create advanced shopping cart rule in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to create a **shopping cart rule** in **Magento 2**.
I have 6 **products** (range product A -> product F) to keep it simple.
Those products cannot be ordered without a valid **discount code**.

1. if cart has one product from range A->F, client cannot add another product from that range into cart (other products are possible).
2. products from range A->F can only be ordered with valid discountcode (if valid, product is free)
3. if cart has only one item and it is from range A->F, shipping is free
4. if cart has more products (other than range A->F) normal shipping, but only product from range A->F is free a order)

What is the best way to accomplish this?